# Is it possible to pass selector as @input in angular component?

Tags: angular

I want to pass an `@Input` to an angular component, like this:

```
<some-component [childComponent]="'<child-component><child-component>'"><some-component>
```

Because I want to reuse the code of `some-component` and the `@Input` value will be dynamic so each time I can pass a new child component inside `some-component`. The `child-component` will be rendered inside `some-component`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks for help.

Comment: HTML added dynamically is not processed by Angular in any way. You shouldn't expect `<child-component>` to become a component if you pass it around as String and then add it to the DOM eventually, also any bindings like `[prop]="..."`, `(fooEvent)="..."`, or `"{{...}}"`, won't do anything. What you can do is to pass component types around and instantiate and add components dynamically. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468

Comment: Read [Here is what you need to know about dynamic components in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular-ac1e96167f9e) to understand why html added dynamically is not processed by Angular